# Relative layout positioning didn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble positioning these views. I want to do like below. I have two radio buttons (rb_), and an edit text (et_) next to the first radio and an expandable list view (lv_) next to the second.

[image]

I tried the following code but couldn't achieve what I want, the et_new_trip got pushed down another line and not to the right of rb_create_new, the lv_old_trip didn't show at all. Any idea why? thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rl_trip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/rg_trip_creation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rb_create_new"
                     style="@style/WrapContentWidthHeight"
                     android:text="New trip"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/et_new_trip"
                  android:layout_height="30dp"
                  android:layout_width="200dp"
                  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rb_create_new"
                  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rb_create_new"
                  android:text="New Trip name"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rb_old_trip"
                     android:layout_height="30dp"
                     android:layout_width="200dp"
                     android:text="Previous trip"/>
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_old_trip"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rb_old_trip"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rb_old_trip"
            />

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: wouldn't this be easier as a vertical LinearLayout, containing a horizontal LinearLayout for each row?

Comment: Agreed, linearlayout is easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enclosed Relative Layout inside Radio Group thats the main Problem. Thats why its behaving like this. Remove Radio Group and your layout will be just fine.

Below id your layout

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_trip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_create_new"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New trip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_new_trip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rb_create_new"
            android:layout_toRighttOf="@+id/rb_create_new"
            android:text="New Trip name" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_old_trip"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rb_create_new"
            android:text="Previous trip" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_old_trip"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rb_old_trip"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rb_old_trip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

If you want them in Radio Button you can do like this, But one thing to be always taken care of is : **Match the Height of Radio Button and the Respective View in Right**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_trip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_trip_creation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_create_new"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="New trip" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_old_trip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Previous trip" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_new_trip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="New Trip name" />

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_old_trip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rb_old_trip"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rb_old_trip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my RadioGroup is inside Relativelayout, not the other way round.

Comment: Reason I want to keep the RadioGroup is to let only one option to be selected.

Comment: Let me try something for you

Comment: Updated answer , Please check

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >   
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radioButton1"
                android:hint="et_new" />

            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radioButton2" >

            </ExpandableListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```